# Change destination of author link to BuddyPress member profile

Tags: author, buddypress

By default, when you click on the author in a post, WP directs you to:

> example.com/author/sample-user/

However, for BuddyPress users, it makes much more sense that it directs the user to the author's BuddyPress profile page:

> example.com/members/sample-user/

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

UPDATE
I'm trying with the following codes

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'change_author_link', 10, 1  );

function change_author_link($link) {

$link = 'http://asiaforum.club/members/' . $author_ID;
return $link;
}
```

But I can't seem to get wordpress to retrieve the author's user ID. Any idea on how to do that (or if this method will work)?

Answer (score 1):

The following codes worked. I added to my child theme's functions.php

```
  add_filter( 'author_link', 'change_author_link', 10, 1  );

  function change_author_link($link) {
   $username=get_the_author_meta('user_nicename');


  $link = 'http://example.com/members/' . $username;
   return $link;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more robust approach:

```
function change_author_link($link) {

   $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

   return bp_core_get_user_domain( $user_id );
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'change_author_link', 10, 1  );
```

Comment: That's great! However, I don't think user ID works with buddypress because the profile link is generated with usernames. That's why my code uses "user_nicename". I suppose simply username works too. When you use user_ID it will only return the numerical ID assigned by the system, which buddy press doesn't recognize

Comment: Read: http://hookr.io/functions/bp_core_get_user_domain/